# Can you install Windows Messaging on Windows Server Core 2008 R2

Tags: windows, msmq, windows-server-core

We have Windows Server Core 2008 R2. We have successfully installed .NET and the Visual C++ runtimes.

Our application requires the ability to post messages to an MSMQ server

To be clear we do not want to install MSMQ server on the machine.

However we want to be able to post messages to a remote MSMQ server so we need to install the client parts of Windows Messaging.

Has anybody succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/08/windows-server-2008-core-installation-msmq-batteries-not-included.aspx) which covers MSMQ and Windows Server 2008 Core installation. Basically, no.